# Can iOS enterprise App with expired provision file use 3D Touch feature?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, 3dtouch

I developed an iOS App built with enterprise certification.

Can the app still use 3D touch even if its provision file expired?

I want to put a '`Help page when cannot open app`' url in 3D touch list.

Comment: I actually really likethis idea for helping enterprise users when a profile expires.  I really wish Apple would let apps provide custom messages for expired profiles to let users know they need to get a new version of the app with a non expired profile.  Not all enterprises use MDM to manage apps / profiles.

Comment: @wottle  Those employees in my company never update enterprise apps. Really embarrassing when asked for help.

Comment: Yeah. Short of managing the devices and pushing updated apps / profiles, I haven't found a great solution to this.  We have the apps themselves build in checks for new versions, and request the users install new versions when available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since your app will not start when the profile is expired. Thus the 3D touch menu wil show but selecting any of the option will not do anything.